# How to select second string in a list using C#?

Tags: c#, string, list

I have this code which will sometimes just have one string in it and sometimes have two.  Basically when it has two strings I want to be able to select the second string as at the moment it is selecting the first string in the list.

 Here is my code:

```
List<string> workGroupIdStringValues = new List<string>();
workGroupIdStringValues = (List<string>)session["WorkGroupIds"];
List<Guid> workGroupIds = workGroupIdStringValues.ConvertAll<Guid>(workGroupIdStringValue => new Guid(workGroupIdStringValue));
```

So "workGroupIdStringValues" will sometimes have a second string, how can I select the second and not the first when there is two strings.  Is it possible, if so how?
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Use LINQ's `workGroupIdStringValues.Last()` to discard all strings but the last one; will work fine if there's just one string.

**Update:** And then of course you have to adapt the code somewhat:

```
var workGroupId = new Guid(((List<string>)session["WorkGroupIds"]).Last());
```

Comment: Of course you can combine this as `workingGroupIdStringValues.Take(2).Last()` if you don't want the third value if it is present

Comment: Sorry this doesnt seem to work,  im getting cannot implicitly convert <string> to string

Comment: @Ben: Please see the update. You can't just simply `.Last()` to your existing code, the type of the expression changes.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
string workGroupIdStringValue = ((List<string>)session["WorkGroupIds"]).Last();
```

Comment: Sorry this doesnt seem to work either, im getting cannot implicitly convert <string> to string again

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this, I think the best is to do

`workGroupIdStringValues.Count` will give you the total amount of objects, and

`workGroupIdStringValues[1]` will return the second entry in your list.

So something like

```
if(workGroupIdStringValues.Count() > 1)
     mystring = workGroupIdStringValues[1];
else
     mystring = workGroupIdStringValues[0];
```

Comment: since it's a list i would use `Count` instead of LINQ's `Count()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
List<Guid> workGroupIds = workGroupIdStringValues.ConvertAll<Guid>(workGroupIdStringValue => new Guid(workGroupIdStringValue));
```

You can do following

```
Guid workGroupId = new Guid(workGroupIdStringValues[workGroupIdStringValues.Count-1]));
```

Comment: This kind of works as it works when I have two strings in my list, but when there is just one string it errors